# CSS Hell simulating TABLE with DIV

Tags: css

I´m trying to simulate a table using only CSS and DIV. The problem is that nothing that I do can perfectly simulate a table layout behavior.

Below is the table layout that I want and immediately below this one, what I could achieve with CSS/DIV:

[image: Layout with Table/CSS and Table/CSS]

## Html/CSS

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Teste</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        table{
            table-layout:fixed;
            width: 333px;
            border-width: 1px;
            border-spacing: 2px;
            border-style: solid;
            border-color: black;
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }
    
        table th, table td
        {
            border-width: 1px;
            padding: 1px;
            border-style: solid;
            border-color: black;
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }
    
        table th.column1, table td.column1{
            width:60px;
            background-color:#CCD9FF;
        }
    
        table th.column2, table td.column2{
            width:100px;
            background-color:#ECFFE5;
        }
    
        table th.column3, table td.column3{
            width:60px;
            background-color:#FFEBE5;
        }
    
        table th.column4, table td.column4{
            width:100px;
            background-color: #FFFFCC;
        }
    
        div#tablecontainer
        {
            width: 328px;
        }
    
        div.tablecontainerrow
        {
            clear:both;
        }
    
        div#tablecontainer div div.column1
        {
            width: 60px;
            float:left;
            border: 1px solid black;
            background-color:#CCD9FF;            
        }
    
        div#tablecontainer div div.column2
        {
            width: 100px;
            float:left;
            border: 1px solid black;
            background-color:#ECFFE5;            
        }

        div#tablecontainer div div.column3
        {
            width: 60px;
            float:left;
            border: 1px solid black;
            background-color:#FFEBE5;            
        }
    
        div#tablecontainer div div.column4
        {
            width: 100px;
            float:left;
            border: 1px solid black;
            background-color:#FFFFCC;            
        }
    
    
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>CSS and TABLE</h1>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th class="column1">Header 1</th>
            <th class="column2">Header 2</th>
            <th class="column3">Header 3</th>
            <th class="column4">Header 4</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="column1">line 1 column 1</td>
            <td class="column2">line 1 column 2</td>
            <td class="column3">line 1 column 3</td>
            <td class="column4">line 2 column 4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="column1">line 2 column 1</td>
            <td class="column2">line 2 column 2</td>
            <td class="column3">line 2 column 3</td>
            <td class="column4">line 2 column 4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="column1">line 3 column 1</td>
            <td class="column2">line 3 column 2</td>
            <td class="column3">line 3 column 3 (more content)</td>
            <td class="column4">line 3 column 4</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <h1>CSS and DIV</h1>
    <div id="tablecontainer">
        <div class="tablecontainerrow">
            <div class="column1">Header 1</div>
            <div class="column2">Header 2</div>
            <div class="column3">Header 3</div>
            <div class="column4">Header 4</div>
            <div class="clear" />
        </div>
        <div class="tablecontainerrow">
            <div class="column1">line 1 column 1</div>
            <div class="column2">line 1 column 2</div>
            <div class="column3">line 1 column 3</div>
            <div class="column4">line 1 column 4</div>
        </div>
        <div class="tablecontainerrow">
            <div class="column1">line 2 column 1</div>
            <div class="column2">line 2 column 2</div>
            <div class="column3">line 2 column 3</div>
            <div class="column4">line 2 column 4</div>
        </div>
        <div class="tablecontainerrow">
            <div class="column1">line 3 column 1</div>
            <div class="column2">line 3 column 2</div>
            <div class="column3">line 3 column 3 (more content)</div>
            <div class="column4">line 3 column 4</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

What might I modify to allow the CSS/DIV layout resembles the CSS/Table?

## Some complementary information

> - Think in this as an exercise (a challenge). So please do not provide me answers saying the use of a table is a better solution for this situation.
> - In fact I´m wondering a solution that can change completely the tabular layout of data to another one simply changing the CSS. In this case, the use of `<table>` is out of question.
> - I want compatibility with IE 7+, FF3+, Chrome 4+.

Thanks!

Comment: Is what you're trying to display a table? If so, use a table.

Comment: why? semantically using a table for tabular data is considered a best practice.

Comment: Agreeing with the posters above, a table makes sense if you are displaying a table.

Comment: Just use a table. But for the question: check for `display: table` `display: table-row` and so on...

Comment: `"I´m trying to simulate a table using only CSS and DIV."` - why?

Comment: @BrunoLM, @Michael, @matchew, @Jeremy, @thirtydot, To explain why to use CSS instead of a table, see the complementary information that I have added in my question.

Comment: @rperson: Alright, I understand what you're saying. Two questions: is the solution provided by @Richard JP Le Guen acceptable? And, you said `"For the sake of compatibility I want to use CSS 2.1."` - but which actual browsers/versions do you need to support?

Comment: @thirtydot, The solution provided by @Richard JP is the best until now. I´m just waiting to see if another good answer is presented before voting in it as correct. I want compatibility with IE 7+, FF3+, Chrome 4+. I think I´ve understood your point: if I want compatibility with IE7, CSS 2.0 in not fully supported. So I´m updating the `complementary information`. Thanks.

Comment: @rperson: In another comment, you said: `"what about the situation in which a tabular data view is only one among several other presentation layouts that can be choosen"` - how is the presentational layout changed? Is it a server-side thing, or do you use JavaScript to change the view client-side? I ask because if you *are* using JavaScript, then it can also be used to fix up the `height`s of your `div`s.

Comment: @thirtydot, say that the user can choose from several options of layouts/skins in your profile administration area, then its options are saved and used to decide the CSS that gets loaded when the page is rendered. Its a server-side thing.

Comment: @rperson: In that case, the "proper solution" is to properly abstract your data outputting so that you can also output different HTML (like a real `table`) for each "layout/skin". Either do that, or drop support for IE7 and use the `display: table-cell` properties.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Again, you should use a table.

But if this is just an exercise in CSS, for kicks...

- Ditch the `<div class="clear" />`.
- Ditch the background colors and use [faux-columns](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/) instead.
- Don't put borders around the individual cells; instead put them around the rows.
- Give the rows an `overflow:hidden`

Like so: http://jsfiddle.net/39F88/

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Teste</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        table{
            table-layout:fixed;
            width: 333px;
            border-width: 1px;
            border-spacing: 2px;
            border-style: solid;
            border-color: black;
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }

        table th, table td
        {
            border-width: 1px;
            padding: 1px;
            border-style: solid;
            border-color: black;
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }

        table th.column1, table td.column1{
            width:60px;
            background-color:#CCD9FF;
        }

        table th.column2, table td.column2{
            width:100px;
            background-color:#ECFFE5;
        }

        table th.column3, table td.column3{
            width:60px;
            background-color:#FFEBE5;
        }

        table th.column4, table td.column4{
            width:100px;
            background-color: #FFFFCC;
        }

        div#tablecontainer
        {
            width:335px;
            border-top:1px solid black;
            background:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZsO5U.png) TOP LEFT REPEAT-Y;
        }

        div.tablecontainerrow
        {
            clear:both;
            overflow:hidden;
            border:1px solid black;
            border-top:none;
        }

        div#tablecontainer div div.column1
        {
            width: 62px;
            float:left;
        }

        div#tablecontainer div div.column2
        {
            width: 104px;
            float:left;
        }

        div#tablecontainer div div.column3
        {
            width: 62px;
            float:left;
        }

        div#tablecontainer div div.column4
        {
            width: 104px;
            float:left;
        }


    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>CSS and TABLE</h1>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th class="column1">Header 1</th>
            <th class="column2">Header 2</th>
            <th class="column3">Header 3</th>
            <th class="column4">Header 4</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="column1">line 1 column 1</td>
            <td class="column2">line 1 column 2</td>
            <td class="column3">line 1 column 3</td>
            <td class="column4">line 2 column 4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="column1">line 2 column 1</td>
            <td class="column2">line 2 column 2</td>
            <td class="column3">line 2 column 3</td>
            <td class="column4">line 2 column 4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="column1">line 3 column 1</td>
            <td class="column2">line 3 column 2</td>
            <td class="column3">line 3 column 3 (more content)</td>
            <td class="column4">line 3 column 4</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <h1>CSS and DIV</h1>
    <div id="tablecontainer">
        <div class="tablecontainerrow">
            <div class="column1">Header 1</div>
            <div class="column2">Header 2</div>
            <div class="column3">Header 3</div>
            <div class="column4">Header 4</div>
        </div>
        <div class="tablecontainerrow">
            <div class="column1">line 1 column 1</div>
            <div class="column2">line 1 column 2</div>
            <div class="column3">line 1 column 3</div>
            <div class="column4">line 1 column 4</div>
        </div>
        <div class="tablecontainerrow">
            <div class="column1">line 2 column 1</div>
            <div class="column2">line 2 column 2</div>
            <div class="column3">line 2 column 3</div>
            <div class="column4">line 2 column 4</div>
        </div>
        <div class="tablecontainerrow">
            <div class="column1">line 3 column 1</div>
            <div class="column2">line 3 column 2</div>
            <div class="column3">line 3 column 3 (more content)</div>
            <div class="column4">line 3 column 4</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That was a very good solution. It only doesn´t work with IE6. It was flagged as correct. Thank you!

Comment: I presume that I cannot get a vertical alignment of the text as the table does, isn´t it?

Comment: @rperson - You mean like you would if you used [`vertical-align`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-vertical-align) property? No, you'd have to use `display:table-cell` for that to work, or you'll have to fake it with `padding`.

Comment: tank you, really help on IE and accessibility.

Comment: @forX - Remember: if you're talking about tabular data, it doesn't hurt accessibility to put it in a table.

Comment: @RichardJPLeGuen  Use CSS-based Layouts Instead of Table-based Layouts http://www.tbs-sct.gc.ca/ws-nw/wa-aw/wa-aw-guid-eng.asp#developwebsite

Answer (score 6):

Using tables to layout pages is not very professional but using tables to display tables is perfectly ok - this is for what they should be used. Emulating tables using divs and css is taking css layouting way too far.

Comment: I agree, but what about the situation in which a tabular data view is only one among several other presentation layouts that can be choosen by the user?

Comment: Radical change of layout of a page (or its part) using css *only* may be difficult. It is not always possible to totally separate structure of a document (HTML) from its presentation (CSS), at least without heavy effort. To achieve some effects or work-around some browser specific bugs, you have to change the structure (e.g. add some magic divs). To make it possible, cheaper and less frustrating, I would consider replacing both, CSS and HTML. The replace can be done on the server side in case of traditional pages or on the client side (using JS) when page refresh is not desired.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. They are pertinent and make sense to me.

Answer (score 2):

This is a horrid answer, I can't believe I'm even suggesting it, BUT, if you are hell bent on making a table out of divs...

> As is stated in the comments, if it is a table, use a table, tables are not evil, they were just overused at one time to do things they weren't designed for. They are designed to display tabular data so if you can, use them.

**This is only suggested if you MUST make a table with divs**

There is a little known display property in CSS to help you with this, read here: [table-cell css.](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_class_display.asp)

Again, just use a table, if you can.

Comment: And using `display:table-cell` on anything but a `td` element causes all sorts of gremlins to come out in browsers.  Highly frowned down upon and from a semantic point of view, it is actually incorrect to use divs to present tabular data.

Comment: Using table-cell on a td is like writing the word DOG on your pet beagle.

Comment: its only there to reset back to the correct value in case you have issues with inheritance from parent values. It actually started as (browser) rendering mode and the css value was added to manually trigger that rendering mode. Each browser is slightly different in when that mode will actually produce the required results since misused of that value can lead to situations where the rendering engine is told to render a table cell with no parent row, rowset, or table.

Answer (score 1):

If you are presenting tabular data (multiple attributes of multiple similar entities, aka *tabular* data), use a `<table>` tag

Answer (score 1):

```
div#tablecontainer
{
    width: 328px;
    display:table;
}

div.tablecontainerrow
{
    display:table-row;
}
div.tablecontainerrow div{
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Of course, I think most current browsers handle this, except for MSIE...

Comment: Aight, granted, this is next to useless, and about it's only purpose is to check whether browsers accurately support the CSS feature. It could do _some_ good in XHTML with embedded XML, but that's about it.

Comment: it is a interesting solution, but it is a pity that `display: table` only works with IE 8.0 and above. Unfortunately, I think that IE 7.0 yet is a must. Don´t you?

Comment: Depends: on the public internet, supporting MSIE  7 (and for _some_ sites, MSIE 6, check the user-agent stats of a particular site) is mostly a must. Then again, as I said, about it's only use is when embedding displayable XML in XHTML, which I've seen more on intranets then on the internet (but that may be my limited experience), and in a controlled environment you of course have a say which browsers are going to be used.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the only way to get around this is to explicitly set the height of your 'columns', otherwise the divs will default to height:auto, and will only be as big as the content within them. Setting the height can be dangerous if you have content that requires more space than the height will allow.

Comment: As a general rule, setting height is trying to force a presentation-layer (HTML) that was explicitly designed to NOT enforce vertical layout-- to enforce vertical layout-- and as such, is problematic-- both in theory and practice.

Comment: it is not the solution, because column´s content is dynamic and I don´t know its length.

Answer (score 0):

Super annoying problem, just came up at work. I usually use an background to solve this problem but since everything needs to be responsive now it is annoying to make images for each Media Query. This is the only time I would use JavaScript to achieve what I want. Stupid that it is not supported.

**HTML:**

```
<ul class="table-layout clearfix">
    <li>
        <p>Header 1</p>
        <p>Header 1</p>
        <p>Header 1</p>
        <p>Header 1</p>
        <p>Header 1</p>
        <p>Header 1</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <p>Header 1</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <p>Header 1</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var height = 0;

    $(".table-layout li").each(function(i){

        if($(this).height() > height)
            height = $(this).height();

    });

    $(".table-layout li").css("height", height + 'px');

});
```

**CSS:**

```
    /**
     * Markup free clearing.
     *
     * @see http://perishablepress.com/press/2009/12/06/new-clearfix-hack
     */
    .clearfix:after {
      content: ".";
      display: block;
      height: 0;
      clear: both;
      visibility: hidden;
    }
    /* IE6 */
    * html .clearfix {
      height: 1%;
    }
    /* IE7 */
    *:first-child + html .clearfix {
      min-height: 1%;
    }

    ul, li{
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        list-style-type:none;
    }

    ul{
        width:335px;
        overflow:hidden;
    }

    ul li{
        width: 31.5%;
        float:left;
        border:1px solid #000;
        margin-right:4px;
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kXrn5/6/

Answer (score 0):

Here's my attempt.  It's probably not perfect, but it's a start.  For me, It's working on the newest Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Opera, IE10, and 
IE9.  Sorry, I don't have an IE7 to test with.  I doubt it works, as IE7 was hard to deal with.

http://jsfiddle.net/nluis3294/uLuof882/

I think we all agree that you should use tables for tabular data, and divs for non-tabular data.  In the ideal world, I think that's what everyone would do.

However, it's also ok to say that I want my non-tabular data to be aligned in a grid and that those rows and columns should stretch like a regular html table.  That's a design choice, and it's totally legitimate.  That is where the difficulties lie.  You can use tables, which are much easier, but technically wrong.  Or, you can use divs, and have to rely on tricks like background images, and faux columns, and spacers to get it to look like tables.

Using faux columns doesn't seem "correct" to me either.  If you want to change the width of a column, you'd need to edit the background image.  And using a background image to set background color seems weird to me.  I have similar reservations about other tricks such as Psuedo columns, or tricks regarding negative margins.  In my oppinion, they should just change the css to allow a simple way to get something that looks like a grid without tricks.

```
<div class="testTable">
<div class="testRow">
    <div class="testColumn1">
        aa
    </div>
    <div class="testColumn2">
        bb<br/>
        bbb2
    </div>
    <div class="testColumn3">
        cc<br/>
        cccc2
    </div>
    <div class="testColumn4">
        dddddd<br/>
        dddddd
    </div>

</div>
<div class="testRow">
    <div class="testColumn1">
        aa
    </div>
    <div class="testColumn2">
        bb<br/>
        bbb2
    </div>
    <div class="testColumn3">
        cc<br/>
        cccc2
    </div>
    <div class="testColumn4">
        dddddd<br/>
        dddddd
    </div>

</div>

<div class="testRow">
    <div class="testColumn1">
        aaa aaa
    </div>
    <div class="testColumn2">
        bb<br/>
        bbb2<br/>
        bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb3

    </div>
    <div class="testColumn3">
        cccccc<br/>

    </div>
    <div class="testColumn4">
        ddddd<br/>
        ddd
    </div>  
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.testTable{
    width: 30%; display: table; table-layout: auto;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;

}

div.testRow{
    display: table-row; width: 100%; 
white-space: nowrap;
    vertical-align:top;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;

}

div.testColumn1{
    display: table-cell; height:100%; min-width: 25%; background-color: #CCD9FF;    
    vertical-align:top;
    padding: 0.2em;

    border: 1px solid black;
    margin:0;

}

div.testColumn2{
    display: table-cell; height:100%; min-width: 25%;background-color: #ECFFE5; 
    vertical-align:top;
    padding: 0.2em;

    border: 1px solid black;
    margin:0;

}
div.testColumn3{
    display: table-cell; height:100%; min-width: 25%;background-color: #FFEBE5; 
    vertical-align:top;
    padding: 0.2em;

    border: 1px solid black;
    margin:0;

}

div.testColumn4{
    display: table-cell; height:100%; min-width: 25%;background-color: #FFFFCC; 
    vertical-align:top;
    padding: 0.2em;

    border: 1px solid black;
    margin:0;
}
```