# Break html table to make it visible without horizontal scrollbar

Tags: html, html-table, line-breaks

Is it possible to break a table horizontally at screen width and show left headers + data in next line so that the entire table is visible without horizontal scrollbar? (Or is this possible to print the table in this format?)

Example:

from

```
col1 col2 col3 col4 col5
------------------------
dat0 dat1 dat2 dat3 dat4
dat5 dat6 dat7 dat8 dat9
```

to

```
col1 col2 col3
--------------
dat0 dat1 dat2 
dat5 dat6 dat7

col4 col5
---------
dat3 dat4
dat8 dat9
```

Answer (score 1):

short answer: no.

you can simulate tables by using divs, see [CSS Hell simulating TABLE with DIV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6299033/css-hell-simulating-table-with-div) to get you started.

Once you have divs, you can do the funky stuff you describe, maybe mixing in some javascript into you html/css concoction.

Comment: OK, thanks. Is there another solution to print a table with many columns on one or more pages with a normal font size?

Comment: it might be possible to break up the table using javascript.

Comment: How do you feel about about placing the table, full width, in a div that has (horizontal) scrolling enabled (css style property overflow:scroll;)?

Answer (score 0):

The Best way is TABLELESS DESIGN. Just go with DIV

```
<div id="outercontainer" style="overflow:hidden">

<div id="inner1" style="float:left;">
dat0
dat5
</div>

<div id="inner2" style="float:left;">
dat1
dat6
</div>

....

<div id="innern" style="float:left;">
...
</div>

</div><!--outercontainer-->
```

Now the inner DIVs will behave like . But once a particular  reaches the right corner it breaks itself to new Line.