# CSS - float:left alignment issue

Tags: css, css-float

I am building a forum listing using DIVs and here is the one I have

```
/* forum like build */
.myForum{
    float: left;
    width: 620px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    border: 2px solid #0F5C8E;
    padding: 1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
}

.myForum > .header {
    height:10px;
    background-color: #adcbe7;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #0F5C8E;

    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 2px;
    overflow: hidden;
    height:20px;
}



.myForum > .myrow {
    padding-left: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #0F5C8E;
   height:57px;
   background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

.myForum > .myrow > .photo {    
    overflow: hidden;
    width:105px;
    float:left;
    text-align:center;
    padding-right: 2px;
    padding-top:2px;    
    height:57px;
}

.myForum > .myrow > .content {
    padding-left: 3px;
    padding-right: 3px;
    overflow: hidden;
    width:450px;
    float:left;
    border-left: 1px solid #0F5C8E;
    border-right: 1px solid #0F5C8E;
    height:57px;

}
.myForum > .myrow > .mycount {
    padding-right: 1px;
    padding-bottom: 1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    float:left;
    height:57px;
    padding-left:3px;

}

.myForum > .myrow > .content > a {
    color: #013E99;
    font: bold 0.8em/1.3 arial,helvetica,sans-serif;
    margin-top: 0;
}

.myForum > .myrow > .content > p  {
    font: normal 0.7em/1.3 arial,helvetica,sans-serif;
    margin-bottom:2px;
    color:#878787;
}
.myForum > .myrow > .content > p > a {
    color: #0066CC;
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ytAud/1/

You can see alignment got messed up .

If I add extra **padding-top** to the third div (**.myForum > .myrow > .mycount**) , the alignment works just fine . But that disturbs the vertical lines ( second vertical line). You can see the modified one below

http://jsfiddle.net/ytAud/2/

(I thought of using tables, But I see latest sites started using DIVs even for listings)

Comment: For generated content if you're not wanting to use tables(which DO have their place in the web still) You might want to use an unordered list

Comment: Yeah, forget the TABLES for sure. Even better: forget the DIVs. Use a styled unordered list.

Comment: Look this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6299033/css-hell-simulating-table-with-div

Comment: Thank You Bluetoft , Diodeus and Ali for your comments . I will try with Styles unordered list for that . Can I know any examples or links in handy ..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your padding on photo is causing the issue. Since there isn't enough hight in each row its over laping into the next. Simple example to show the issue. (It can be solved by either removing the padding or adding more height)

Change:

```
.myForum > .myrow > .photo {    
overflow: hidden;
width:105px;
float:left;
text-align:center;
padding-right: 2px;
padding-top:2px;    
height:57px;
}
```

To

```
.myForum > .myrow > .photo {    
overflow: hidden;
width:105px;
float:left;
text-align:center;   
height:57px;
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/ytAud/3/)

Comment: Thanks for finding my mistake . I was lost .

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the most syntactically correct way, but it works in your example:

> .myForum > .myrow {
>   clear: both;
>   }

Comment: No problem.  If you use this solution, let everyone know by setting it as the answer.